# Which CSOM nuget package should I use for SharePoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server

I want to upgrade from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint 2019 (on prem). We have C# code which uses the CSOM libraries from the GAC which are installed with the SP 2013 client SDK msi package.

I see that msi SDK exist for SP2013 and SP2016 but not for SP2019. I read that SDK msi package will not be developed for SP2019, because the correct way is to use nuget package instead of referencing GAC dlls, because the GAC dlls override the dlls from the package. [source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qPmr7c2B0uk)

With this in mind on Nuget there are 3 packages:

- [Microsoft.SharePoint2013.CSOM](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePoint2013.CSOM/) (SharePoint 2013 - May 2018 CU)
- [Microsoft.SharePoint2016.CSOM](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePoint2016.CSOM/) (SharePoint 2016 - May 2018 CU version)
- [Microsoft.SharePoint2019.CSOM](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePoint2019.CSOM/) (SharePoint 2019 - RTM - October 2018)

I was going to use the package for SP2019, but the strange thing is that it is uploaded 2018, and the packages for 2013 and 2016 are updated more recently (2019). And the same source I quoted above says the the SP2016 CSOM libraries are actually compatible with SP2019.

And I am kind of confused. Which nuget package should I use for SP2019?

Comment: Did you find the answer for this? we are on the same boat. Could you please suggest which package we should use for sharePoint 2019 on-premise

Comment: I went with using the package for 2019: Microsoft.SharePoint2019.CSOM (16.0.10337.12109). I did some testing with the on-prem SP2019 and it works ok for the last couple of months

Answer (score 0):

Use the nuget package from here - https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharePoint.2019.CSOM.16.0.10342.12113/ . This was last updated on 25/04/2019